# Unable to update to 16.04 from 15.10

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10. I want to update to 16.04. But the Software updater does not show the required update. is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its just matter of wait. If you really want then can do it by using developer release. This is not recommended as it is prone to bugs. You have to run command

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [The Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes)**,**

- Open the **Software & Updates** Setting in **System Settings**.
- Select the **Updates** tab.
- Set the **Notify me of a new Ubuntu version** dropdown menu to **`For any new version`** if you are using 15.10, or set it to **`long-term support versions`** if you are using 14.04 LTS.
- **Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type in `update-manager`** into the command box. Software Updater should open up and tell you: `New distribution release '16.04 LTS' is available`.
- **Click Upgrade** and follow the on-screen instructions.

UPDATE: The release notes says that upgrade from 14.04 will only be available on the 16.04.1 release in about 3 months.

Comment: I did all that of course :)

Comment: @DimitriosMataras See my edited answer: The release notes says that upgrade from 14.04 will only be available on the 16.04.1 release in about 3 months.